# GUI in using QT with data from c program

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, libraries

I am quite new to C++ and C. And I am wondering how to import some data from C program and using it in order to draw a GUI in c++ ?

what happen if the C program has its own Library? how to include it ?

I am working with Linux platform.

Thanks

Comment: That is a vague question. What does "I am wondering how to import some data from C program and using it in order to draw a GUI in c++" mean. What is the C program, what is the GUI stuff that you want to use from C++, and why mix C and C++? Are you trying to call C functions from some C++ functions? You are familiar with your problem, but we are not. The clearer and more specific you can be the more accurate and helpful we can be.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is largely backwards compatible with C, so you can import the data from the C program "as is".

To link a C library to a QT application follow the instructions in the QMake manual to specify that the program should be linked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I add the c library to my project. Although I am still do not know how to use QT as front end for c program. should I just export all the c files to the project ?? any help

Comment: @RikoRm: There are two options:  You can use a packaged binary version of library, or you can include the library as source.  Which library is it?  What is the library called?  Where did you get it?